# Internship USA and sponsor immigration

Tags: internship, international

Currently, I want to apply to one of the companies in the US for a training internship for  computer science students. However, unfortunately I have a problem. I must mark or uncheck this statement:

Will you now or in the future require company X to commence (“sponsor”) an immigration case in order to employ you?

I do not plan to stay in the US for more than 12 weeks, but I do not rule out that in the future I will want to move here, although I have no idea if I want to be with the company X in the distant future.
1. If I check "No", will my flight and visa costs have to be covered by myself?
2. If I check "no", can the company state that I do not care to cooperate with them?
3. If I say yes, will the company think  that I really want to settle in the US and they are just a tool for this?

I am asking for advice on this matter.
Greetings from Eastern Europe

Comment: I'm very surprised that a non-US person can come to the US and work for 12 weeks?

Comment: That's  common practice

Comment: Wow awesome.  Enjoy, then!

Comment: What visa do you get for that?

Comment: @Fattie there are several visas for business people, residents, business owners,for students etc.split between usage case and requirements of the person depending on their citizenship and status.there usually are different criteria that need to be fulfilled to be eligible.

Comment: It is not clear from your question: Is this on the company's form or on the visa form? The answer to you question depends.

Comment: company's form .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use only official government sources to answer immigration questions.

**Get in touch with the authorities in question directly.**

Best place to start is visiting the embassy website of the country you want to stay in, that countrys governments official website or legal advice in immigration matters.

**Your answer will depend on your nationality and your personal / professional circumstances.**

Comment: But my question is not only about immigration but also about how X company will interpret decisions

Comment: @VirtualUser yes, but in order to understand how they'll interpret, you need to know what that question actually means for you,thus how you NEED to answer it (you most likely don't have a choice, you either need a sponsor or not)and what likely consequence the company draws in your case.You shouldn't rely on what is said on the internet.These things need to come from a reliable,official source.

Comment: I checked on USA embassy in my country and there is only about M-1 visa, but nothing what can give me more details about that :(

Comment: @VirtualUser that's not so good.Is it in the EU, what country? It might help to check about EU citizens if you are in a member country.Also have a look at your countrys website for potential information.Maybe the university or agency through which you're making the internship program can help you out?The U.S. Immigration website should also help.if nothing works maybe it's best to call as you're a student who wants to intern at the moment.and you can ask what repercussions it might have for the companys decision depending on what you enter.

Comment: Yes, I am citizen of member country. Thanks for your advice, I will try them all!

Answer (score 0):

The question "Will you now or in the future require company X to commence (“sponsor”) an immigration case in order to employ you? " isn't about how long you want to stay in the USA or how long you want to work. Or the cost of your flight, visa application, accommodation etc.

Its about your visa and if you can legally work in the USA. If you answer incorrectly, it is entirely possible that the company will simply terminate your employment when you arrive since you can't legally work and just ignore you since you have been unfaithful to them. Or you may just be denied a visa in the first place since you plan to work in the USA but have no one to guarantee you are working there (since you answered no).

I don't know the details, but you will need to check with proper authorities and get the requirements of the visa you are applying for that lets you go, stay and work in the USA.